# C# - Call a function in a parent form

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to call a function in a main form from another form... Already got to call a simple function, by declaring it public static in main form, yet I can't call the needed one.
The function to call:

```
    public static void spotcall()
    {
        string dial = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("INTERCOMCS").GetValue("DIAL").ToString();
        MainForm.txtSendKeys.Text = dial;// Here it asks me for a reference to an object.


        foreach (char c in txtSendKeys.Text)
        {
            sideapp.Keyboard.SendKey(c.ToString(), checkBoxPrivate.Checked);
        }
        txtSendKeys.Clear();
    }
```

The procedure I use to call it from a child form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Hoho";
        MainForm.spotcall();
    }
```

I completely admit that I lack some theory about C#, but as it often happens, I just have to do it for my work, so I expect to get help if by chance I don't get to the solution by myself. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you give us error message you're getting? It's not compiling, right? What does the compiler say?

Comment: It asks me for and objects reference for "txtSendKeys". The message is in french, so can't get you the exact text, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct way to do this is to use delegates. This way your form (window) does not have to know anything about the parent form (the form can be opened from different parent forms).

Let's say we want to call a function in the parent form when the child form is closed (not showing the form as modal).

At the top of your child form create a delegate:

```
    public delegate void CloseEvent();
    public CloseEvent WindowClosed;
```

Create the form closing event and have it call your delegate:

```
    private void child_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      WindowClosed();
    }
```

A button in the parent form can show the child form and set the callback:

```
    private ChildForm childform = null;

    private void buttonShowChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (childform == null)
      {
        childform = new ChildForm();
        childform.WindowClosed += childClosed;
        childform.Show();
      } else
      {
        childform.BringToFront();
      }
    }

    private void childClosed()
    {
        childform = null;
    }
```

In this example we use a button to open a new form that does not block the parent form. If the user tries to open the form a second time, we just bring the existing form to the front to show it to the user. When the form is closed we set the object to null so that next time we click the button a new form is opened because the old was disposed when closed.

Best regards
  Hans Milling...

Answer (score 9):

You cannot reference instances of controls on your `MainForm` in a static method.  Like the compiler is telling you, you need an instance of the form in order to update things like TextBoxes.  Without an instance, where would the values you are trying to update go?

I'm not sure exactly how the child form is being created, but one way you could call methods on your `MainForm` would be to provide a reference to your `MainForm` instance directly to the child form.  This could be through the constructor or some public property.

**For example**

```
public class ChildForm : Form {

    public MainForm MyParent { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Hoho";

        // Now your child can access the instance of MainForm directly
        this.MyParent.spotcall(); 
    }   

}
```

Assuming you are creating `ChildForm` inside of `MainForm` the code to give the child a reference is pretty simple:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.MyParent = this; // this is a `MainForm` in this case
childForm.Show();
```

You would also need to make `spotcall` an instance method and not a static method, and remove the static reference to `MainForm` in your code:

```
public void spotcall()
{
    string dial = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("INTERCOMCS").GetValue("DIAL").ToString();
    // Now it no longer asks you for a reference, you have one!
    txtSendKeys.Text = dial;

    foreach (char c in txtSendKeys.Text)
    {
        sideapp.Keyboard.SendKey(c.ToString(), checkBoxPrivate.Checked);
    }
    txtSendKeys.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a static function, you may not reference global variables inside the function that aren't static as well.

So in order for spotcall to be static, you have to remove the reference to the txtSendKeys (I'm assuming this is a text box that you have created elsewhere in the form) or txtSendKeys must be declared within the static function.

Additional:

You obtained the value for txtSendKeys.Text in the previous line, via variable dial. Instead of referencing txtSendKeys.Text at all, I imagine you could simply use the variable dial to complete the function and leave the function static (you clear it at the end anyway).

```
public static void spotcall()
    {
        string dial = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("INTERCOMCS").GetValue("DIAL").ToString();


        foreach (char c in dial)
        {
            sideapp.Keyboard.SendKey(c.ToString(), checkBoxPrivate.Checked);
        }            
    }
```

Although, that wouldn't overcome the same issue you would likely run into with checkBoxPrivate.Checked.

You could change it to take a boolean argument.

```
public static void spotcall(Boolean PrivateChecked)
    {
        string dial = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("INTERCOMCS").GetValue("DIAL").ToString();               

        foreach (char c in dial)
        {
            sideapp.Keyboard.SendKey(c.ToString(), PrivateChecked);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think he needs the reverse: spotcall() needs to be an instance method. txtSendKeys is probably a property bound to a control created in the form designer. He can't declare it elsewhere and he can't do anything useful without it. He just needs to get ahold of the instance of MainForm in the place where he calls spotcall().

Comment: I disagree, respectfully.  He obtained the value for txtSendKeys.Text in the previous line, via variable dial.  Instead of referencing txtSendKeys.Text at all, I imagine he could simply use the variable dial to complete the function and leave the function static (he clears it at the end anyway).  Although, that wouldn't overcome the same issue he would likely run into with checkBoxPrivate.Checked... but hopefully the resolution of this issue would lead him to the resolution of that as well.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I hadn't paid enough attention to what his code was actually doing. You're perfectly correct, txtSendKeys doesn't belong there at all. He's using a UI element as a redundant temp variable. All he's really doing is sending the value of a registry key someplace else. Thanks for disagreeing a lot more respectfully than I actually deserved! :)

Comment: You should put that in your answer -- everybody's talking about static vs instance, but the totally gratuitous use of txtSendKeys is actually a more fundamental error. I'm not gonna put that in my own answer because you caught it.

Comment: Hey, I finally think I complicated things too much... It wasn't even a child form, but just an other one. I finally got to the thing by putting the whole function in my "child form", modifying it in order to kick out all that refers to "MainForm". Thanks for your help, that's really enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the shared code in a third class that's visible to both forms.  So, for example:

```
public class static HelperFunctions
{

    public static void spotcall()
    {
        . . . 
    }
}
```

Then replace

```
MainForm.spotcall()
```

with

```
HelperFunctions.spotcall()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access non-static members in static context, which means you have to made txtSendKeys static, or make your function non-static.

Answer (score 0):

The `MainForm` is just a class. It has the structure of the class. But the only data you can get from it is `static` data.

But an `instance` of that class appears when you do: `MainForm MyFormInstance = new MainForm();`

The `MainForm` can be used only to access static members (methods, properties...).
When you want to get the `txtSendKeys`, you must get it from an instance (object reference). That's because the textbox is not static, so it only exists in instances of the form.

So, you should do the following:

- Make `spotcall` NOT static.
- Put in child form a variable `MainForm MyParentMainForm;`
- When you call the child, set that MyParentMainForm with the instance of the mainform. If it's being called from the main form, you can get the instance with the `this` keyword.
- Inside child form, call `MyParentMainForm.spotcall`

---

PS: I'm not sure if there's something like a real child form or if you just call new forms from another. If there's really a `child` form, you can get the `Parent` property to access the instance of the main form.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a "design pattern" issue, which I'll elaborate on, but I can try to explain the most direct way to solve this if you don't expect this program to change very much. "Static" things only exist **once** - once in the entire application. When a variable or function is static, it's much easier to access from anywhere in the program; but you can't access an object's associated data, because you're not pointing to a particular instance of that object (ie, you have seven MainForms. Which one are you calling this function on?) Since standard WinForm design expects you could have seven copies of MainForm displaying, all variables associated are going to be *instance* variables, or non-static. However, if you expect never to have a second MainForm, then you can take the "singleton" approach, and have an easy way of accessing your one instance.

```
partial class MainForm {

    // only including the code that I'm adding; I'm sure there's a lot of stuff in your form.
    public static MainForm Instance { public get; private set; }

    protected void onInitialize() { // You need to hook this part up yourself.
        Instance = this;
    }
}

partial class SubForm {
    protected void onImportantButton() {
        MainForm.Instance.doImportantThing()
    }
}
```

Putting too much active data-changing logic in form classes is a pretty common issue with many beginners' code. That's not a horrible thing - you wouldn't want to be making 5 controlling classes just for a simple thing you're trying. As code gets more complex, you start to find some things would make more sense to move to a "sublevel" of classes that don't interact with the user (so, some day, if this is being re-coded as a server program, you could throw away the form classes, and just use the logic classes - theoretically speaking). It also takes some time for many programmers to understand the whole concept of object "instances", and the "context" that a function is called in.

Comment: This is horrible practice and will result in propagating bad design and making it that much harder for people to learn how to *properly* address this problem.

Comment: When a beginner is learning on the job, while being expected to quickly write code with actual use, it's almost certain that one is not going to be writing proper design the first few times; in some ways, I think it's more important to let people make the straightforward design-pattern mistakes early on, so they can understand better patterns when they write later programs. But asking someone to completely rewrite a program they wrote quickly for their job is a real down-putter. That said, my belief is that this is a small program that won't ever scale upward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Yet, even though my part of code is something really basic, I'm actually intented to add a functionnality to a huge thing, that is actuallly an SDK of a side application, that I cannot put upside-down ;) Btw, it's very bad concieved as well.