# Winforms call function from main form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I've got a main form open and the main form contains a couple dropdown menus (comboBoxes) that are linked to either a text file (if it exists) or an internal text file (default). The function is like this:

```
public void readFiles()
{
    string regionPath = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Regions.txt";
    string salesPath = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\SalesReps.txt";
    Stream fileStream;
    Stream fileStream1;

    if (File.Exists(regionPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Regions file exists");
        fileStream = File.Open(regionPath, FileMode.Open);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Regions file does not exist");
        var resourceRegions = "SalesMap.Regions.txt";
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        fileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceRegions);
    }

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        var lines = new List<string[]>();
        int Row = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] Line = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            RegionNames.Add(Line[0]);
            RegionParts.Add(Line[1]);
            Row++;
        }
    }

    if (File.Exists(salesPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SalesReps file exists");
        fileStream1 = File.Open(salesPath, FileMode.Open);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SalesReps file does not exist");
        var resourceSales = "SalesMap.SalesReps.txt";
        var assembly1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        fileStream1 = assembly1.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceSales);
    }

    using (StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(fileStream1))
    {
        var lines = new List<string[]>();
        int Row = 0;
        while (!reader1.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] Line = reader1.ReadLine().Split(',');
            SalesRepNames.Add(Line[0]);
            SalesRepEmails.Add(Line[1]);
            SalesRepPhones.Add(Line[2]);
            SalesRepRegions.Add(Line[3]);
            Console.WriteLine(Row);
            Row++;
        }
    }

    comboBoxState.DataSource = RegionNames;
    comboBoxRepresentative.DataSource = SalesRepNames;

    labelRepResult2.Text = "";
    labelContactResult2.Text = "";
}
```

I've also got a "settings" form and I want a button on the settings form to run this function on the main form (thereby forcing the dropdown menus on the main form to refresh their data).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Call a function in a parent form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818925/c-sharp-call-a-function-in-a-parent-form)

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* way would be to inject the main form reference as a dependency to your settings form, store it in a local variable/property, and then use that. In your settings form:

```
public SettingsForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
    TargetMainForm = mainForm;
    // other constructor code
}

private MainForm TargetMainForm { get; set; }

private void DoSettingsThings()
{
    // do settings things here
    TargetMainForm.readFiles();
}
```

And in your main form, when creating a settings form, just do `new SettingsForm(this)`.

However that isn't a good solution, since the settings form shouldn't depend on your main form. A bit cleaner solution would be to make an event on your settings form and subscribe to that from your main form. So in your settings form:

```
public event Action SettingsUpdated;

private void DoSettingsThings()
{
    // do settings things here
    SettingsUpdated?.Invoke();
}
```

And in your main form, when you create the settings form instance:

```
var settingsForm = new SettingsForm();
settingsForm.SettingsUpdated += readFiles;
```

*Keep in mind that both solutions are messy, and that stems from poor (or none) separation of business logic from the presentation layer. But that is out of the scope of this question.*

Comment: Ok, I'm working with your second solution and it seems to be calling the "readFiles" function fine and updating the data that the dropdown is looking at (put in bits of `console.writeline` code to make sure), but the dropdown still seems to be stuck on old data. Any thoughts?.(I tried `comboBox.Update();` and `comboBox.Refresh();` in the `readFiles()` function, but no luck with either)

Comment: @derekantrican That entirely depends on your program. Does your settings form save the data to those text files? Do they get properly closed after being written to? Try debugging all (if any) intermediate steps, check the files with notepad after you write to them. I can't fix your bugs for you. **EDIT**: try not to change your comments like that. Now my response seems wrong.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to imply that I wanted you to debug this for me- just wondering if you knew of anything off the top of your head that might help me out. Also sorry about changing the comment- I hit [Enter] thinking it would make a new line, but instead it submitted the comment (so I had to edit the comment to add the rest of it)